# Windows 10 1709 in combination with C# project targetting .NET 4.7.1

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to target .NET 4.7.1 in C# but I'm getting a error:

> The C$ project xxx is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1", which is not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below.

Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators Update) has .NET v4.7.1 installed. Anyway I try downloading and installing it anyway and getting the error:

> .NET Framework 4.7.1 or later update is already installed on this computer.

Interestingly Visual Studio says it has .NET Framework version 4.7.03052

Has anyone had this specific problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Visual Studio has its own version of .Net which needs installing.
[image]